# What is iOS Team Provisioning Profile with relevant bundle id(iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.mycompany.myapp)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

In Developer Account and Xcode can see iOS Team Provisioning Profile for wildcard and relevant app id's.

1. my Problem is What that iOS Team Provisioning Profile relevant to app id ?
2. don't we need to create specific provisional profile for debug app ? instead that can we use that Team Provisioning Profile(for app ids) for debug, iAP testing,.. etc ?

Thanks
damithH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild card team id means you just give the bundle id with *. once you can made this you can test all your apps on device using that team provisioning profile. it is common profile for all. but it can't use for iAP, iColoud testing..

But thanks to Xcode now it automatically maintains iOS Team Provisioning Profiles (Not a Profile) with a specific AppID. So for the debugging we don't need to create new provisional profiles manually.

It is better to use team provisioning profile(with bundle Id) which is created and managed by Xcode for the debugging process. Which also can test anything like iAP and iCloud.

Comment: using that make build and then test.

Comment: @damithH to test the IAP u can use team provisioning but you will need a seperate product id.

Comment: @Agent, Yeah totally agree with you. So we don't need to create seperate provisioning Profile(Debug) for new apps its created and give us by Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I speak as an owner of an iOS Team Provisioning Profile. This Provisional License allows you to test your applications on an actual device, as apposed to the simulator. The catch is that the device needs to be registered to your Provisioning Profile with its `UDID`, and only up to 100 devices can be registered on one Team Provisioning Profile.